# JavaFX property change listener: null newValue

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have a `cuttingOperationComboBox` ComboBox and a method that changes items and value of this ComboBox:

```
public void changeGlass(Glass newGlass)
{
    ObservableList<Operation> list = new FilteredList<Operation>(ProductGlassCuttingUI.this.operationsDB.getOperationsList(), operation -> operation.getOperationType().toString().equals("RE") &&
            operation.getGlassThickness() == newGlass.getGlassThickness());

    if(!list.contains(this.cuttingOperationComboBox.getValue()))
        cuttingOperationComboBox.setValue(list.get(0));
    cuttingOperationComboBox.setItems(list);
}
```

I also have change listener added to `cuttingOperationComboBox.valueProperty()`.
It is fired first time by `cuttingOperationComboBox.setValue(list.get(0));` and here everything is fine. But when `cuttingOperationComboBox.setItems(list);` fires change listener, newValue in it is null although `list` is not empty. Moreover it happens only when ComboBox is visible. Tobe more precise: cuttingOperationComboBox is displayed in TreeView as a part of TreeCell graphics. As long as tree view node containing combobox is collapsed everything is ok, but when i expand  this node and combobox shows, the above problem appears.
Anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `setItems()` of a `ComboBox` (or other controls involving list of items), the `ComboBox` (or the respective control) will always clear all selection. I believe this is the behavior caused by the underlying [selection model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#selectionModelProperty), and I believe it is the desired behavior for most use-cases.

Without knowing exactly what you are achieving, it's hard to give you an exact solution. If you simply want to retain the value after setting new list, then you might need to keep a copy of the old selection item, and then manually set it in after `setItems()`. If you don't want the `ChangeListener` to respond to `setItems()`, either check for `null` `newValue` in the listener, or keep a boolean flag somewhere that would tell the listener that the particular call was triggered by `setItems()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. What i want to do is just change items of combobox and retain current value if it is element of the new list.To avoid above problem with null newValue i'm checking it before taking any actions in chnage listener, just like You proposed. Now everything works fine but i am just curious why newValue sometimes is null while it should be not. At least i think so, but i'm probably wrong and there is something in ComboBox class that i don't understand.

Comment: @aban Like I said, when you call `setItems()`, you are telling `ComboBox` that "Hey, I'm giving you a brand new list." What happens is that `ComboBox` will assume your originally selected value is no longer correct (because that value may not even be present in your new list), so it will clear that value out, causing a change of value to `null`.